# Why is the below extend incorrect in typescript strictFunctionTypes mode, and correct, when strictFunctionTypes is not enabled?

Tags: typescript

Consider the following code:

```
interface I { x: number; }

interface A {
    cb: (x: I) => void;
}

interface B<T extends I> extends A {
    cb: (x: T) => void;
}
```

Why is the TS error 2430 appearing when declaring the B class? By stating `T extends I`, doesn't that mean, that `T` can be anything that is AT LEAST `I`?

```
Interface 'B<T>' incorrectly extends interface 'A'.
  Types of property 'cb' are incompatible.
    Type '(x: T) => void' is not assignable to type '(x: I) => void'.
      Types of parameters 'x' and 'x' are incompatible.
        Type 'I' is not assignable to type 'T'.
          'I' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'I'.(2430)
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJLIN7IB4C5kgCuAtgEbQDcyAvgLABQDoksiKAgpg8j8gqfgAUeNAEpkAXgB8yAG4B7YABMKDOo3rNo8JMgBCAHgAqyCNkgglAZzQyzF68k4ZuvfkJFHx0uYpVqgA)

Answer (score 0):

With the [`--strictFunctionTypes` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#strict-function-types) disabled, function parameters are checked *bivariantly*, which is unsafe (but sometimes convenient). With it enabled, non-method function parameters are only checked *contravariantly*, which is safe (but sometimes inconvenient). See [Difference between Variance, Covariance, Contravariance and Bivariance in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66410115/2887218) for the terminology, as well as [the Wikipedia entry on variance in computer science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)).

It is safe to *widen* a function parameter type, and unsafe to *narrow* it.  This is the opposite of the rule for a function return type, which is why  you might be confused.  You can see the links above for details about why this is true.  Here, let's just demonstrate that your code is unsafe.

Given your definition of `A`, you can write this function:

```
function f(a: A) { a.cb({ x: 123 }) };
```

That's fine, right?  An `A` has a `cb` function-valued property that accepts any argument of type `I`.  In particular, `{x: 123}` should be fine.

Given your definition of `B<T>`, you can write this value:

```
const b: B<{ x: number, y: string }> = {
    cb: x => console.log(x.y.toUpperCase())
}
```

That's also fine, right? A value of type `B<{x: number, y: string}>` has a `cb` function-valued property that accepts any argument of type `{x: number, y: string}`, which extends `I`.  Such an argument `x` will have a `string`-valued `y` property, so we can access `x.y.toUpperCase()` without a problem.

Now, if `B<T> extends A`, then you should be able to do this:

```
f(b);
```

But of course, at runtime, this will result in the runtime error `TypeError: x.y is undefined`.  And so we have demonstrated that `B<T> extends A` is not true.  The `--strictFunctionTypes` compiler option catches the bug by complaining that `Interface 'B<T>' incorrectly extends interface 'A'`.  Additionally the `f(b)` line above gets a similar error.

You can suppress the error by disabling `--strictFunctionTypes` and allowing unsafe narrowing of function parameters... but if you do so then you need to be very careful not to write any code that does the equivalent of `f(b)` above.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJLIN7IB4C5kgCuAtgEbQDcyAvgFC2iSyIoCCmtyXyCp+AFHjQBKZAF4AfMgBuAe2AATCrToNw0eEmQAhADwAVZBGyQQCgM5opx0xeTssAekdGoUWVAA0nbs7TrmLQByPX0JIORQBA8oCAQwABsATyMTCDNLRg0WZCDWIIA6Hy5eASF9UUkZeSUVemiQczBkPh1dLCEiMmhPZCT8JqhQAHMaKTEObh5W7HEpBvNZBIgChNlhwQKkgrBZAFUABwPoAGE4cwh+YWE62hhCEHjgWRBkGH44fFZRLDgC3n4HXwAEYAEwAZhoomoyju-FIwiofmg7i8tD8rCgwxI6WashgyDASWOuT0QIIJHIUCo-WQgxGVGo4UilhAsma53MwGGIDgpGWhNkyAOcCgcGIECYyHxhOJKDyhXRLgASnsAHL6VAAWQAosgdcrlQB5ZU4LYs5APBQQGCgCAKWhAA)